# Removing leading 0's in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I trim the leading 0's from assoc_userid?

```
SELECT assoc_name
FROM table
WHERE assoc_userid= #arguments.op_id#
```

This column used to be `assoc_id` and would have values like 1,2,3,4,5,..,091,101

Now the values for `assoc_userid` are 001,002,003,004,005,091,101

I tried `WHERE Replace(Ltrim(Replace('assoc_userid', '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') = #arguments.op_id#`

Comment: Alter the column data type to integer. Problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert them to numbers and compare:

```
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(INT, assoc_userid) = TRY_CONVERT(INT, #arguments.op_id#)
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but if this query is run often you'll probably want to make this a persisted computed column on the table so indexing can be used.

Comment: This made it work. They removed the column we had that did not have leading 0's

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use patindex to find index of non-zero character and use substring to get the part of you want.
Here is the sample:

```
declare @input varchar(max)
select @input = '0000100'

select SUBSTRING(@input,PATINDEX('%[^0]%',@input),LEN(@input))
```